# Optional parameters for Rails Image Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

In my current Rails (Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7) app, if I would like to be able to define a helper like:

```
  def product_image_tag(product, size=nil)
    html = '' 
    pi = product.product_images.first.filename
    pi = "products/#{pi}"
    pa = product.product_images.first.alt_text

    if pi.nil? || pi.empty?
      html = image_tag("http://placehold.it/200x200", :size => "200x200")
    else
      html = image_tag(pi, size)
    end

    html

  end
```

...and then call it from a view with either:

```
<%= product_image_tag(p) %>
```

...or:

```
<%= product_image_tag(p, :size => 20x20) %>
```

In other words, I'd like to be able to have this helper method take an optional size parameter. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track. I would do this:

```
def product_image_tag(product, options = {})
  options[:size] ||= "200x200"

  if img = product.product_images.first
    image_tag("products/#{img.filename}", :alt => img.alt_text, :size => options[:size])
  else
    image_tag("http://placehold.it/#{options[:size]}", :size => options[:size])
  end
end
```

Explanations:

Setting the final parameter to an empty hash is a common Ruby idiom, since you can call a method like `product_image_tag(product, :a => '1', :b => '2', :c => '3', ...)` without explicitly making the remaining arguments a hash with `{}`.

`options[:size] ||= "200x200"` sets the :size parameter to 200x200 if one wasn't passed to the method.

`if img = product.product_images.first` - Ruby lets you do assignment inside a condition, which is awesome. In this case, if `product.product_images.first` returns nil (no image), you fall back to your placehold.it link, otherwise display the first image.